# Parsed CSV File shows dot at the beginning

Tags: csv, opencsv

I want to parse the following CSV File:

```
02.01.15,Januar,GEZ,Telekommunikation,"€ 211,44",01_jährlich,Ist
02.01.15,Januar,BGV: Haftpfl. + Unfall,Versicherungen,"€ 171,95",01_jährlich,Ist
```

I use the following code for parsing:

```
  CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
            String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                for (String text : nextLine) {
                    System.out.print(text + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

The output shows a vertically centered dot at the beginning of the first line.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a `UTF-8 signature` at the beginning of the file (looking at the data, your file is probably encoded in `UTF-8`).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

The bytes `0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF` (`ï»¿` in ASCII), convert to a centered dot in `UTF-8`.

You might have to trim that away (or check if you can provide a parameter to `CSVReader` or `FileReader` to skip those bytes). See [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html) for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you check the condition in the while loop you call the `readNext()` method. This consumes the first row without using it. If you tell me what library you are using I can tell you what else you could do. Usually in Java there's a `hasNext()` method for this purpose.

I suppose you're using OpenCSV library, in this case you could do this way

First import the Arraylist library `import java.util.ArrayList;`

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
lines = csvReader.readAll();
for(String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line + " ");
}
```

PS: if you want to print the lines in the same row you should use `System.out.print(line + " ");` because it doesn't make any sense adding the space after the line and then going to a new line (`println()`)